"Prettier" design pattern than nested pattern matching?
I'm doing a uni course on OCaml and need to parse an s-expr into its proper AST representation, using the Containers library
I need to extend the parser to include boolean values but I can't find an elegant way to pattern match the string over just nesting more pattern matches.
So I wonder if there's a prettier way to do it.
So far if the parser detects an `Atomic string "s" it "opens" a nested match case to see if it's an int or a variable name.
...
| `Atomic s ->
  begin
    match int_of_string_opt s with
    | Some n -> Num n
    | None ->
      begin
        match bool_of_string_opt s with
        | Some b -> Bool b
        | None -> Var s
      end
  end
...


This solution works but just by looking I can tell it could be designed better but I'm not familiar enough with OCaml to know how to make it better.

Another option is to use when, for example:
| `Atomic s when is_integer s ->
  Int (int_of_string s)
| `Atomic s when is_bool s ->
  Bool (bool_of_string s)
| `Atomic s -> Var s 


This is neat, the only thing a bit annoying perhaps is that you need to decode values twice, once for the guard and once to actually obtain the value.

Having to decode the value twice is unfortunate, but if you are not worried about performane making the code more readable is worth it. Hopefully the compiler will inline the function and notice the common subexpression.

You can "flatten" the pattern match, at the cost of possibly unnecessarily evaluating bool_of_string_opt s.
match int_of_string_opt s, bool_of_string_opt s with
| Some n, _ -> Num n
| _, Some b -> Bool b
| _, _ -> Var s


It looks like you have a list of parsers that you want to try in sequence until one of them successfully builds a value. Let's say your types are as follows:
type atom = N of int | B of bool
let n v = N v
let b v = B v

I defined also the n and b builder functions because constructors are not functions.
Then, we can build atom parsers, which combine (i) parsers yielding optional values with (ii) builder of atom variants:
let atom_parser parse_opt build s =
  s |> parse_opt |> Option.map build

The list of parser candidates can be defined as follows:
let candidates = [
  atom_parser int_of_string_opt n;
  atom_parser bool_of_string_opt b
]

Each value in the list is a function that possibly return an atom.
Finally, we can use List.find_map to apply a function f to all values in sequence until one call returns a Some output. The test function f here will be given one of our candidate function and must apply it to the string we want to parse, so in fact f in our case is the partial application of this function:
let parse_input string parser = parser string

Hopefully the example below will clarify what this means:
# List.find_map (parse_input "false") candidates;;     
- : atom option = Some (B false)                            

# List.find_map (parse_input "12") candidates;; 
- : atom option = Some (N 12)                                                                                                      

# List.find_map (parse_input "12.45") candidates;; 
- : atom option = None


The last element in candidates should be fun s -> Some (Var s) to implement the default behavior shown by the OP's code.

In which case you can write something like: candidates |> List.find_map (parse_input "12") |> Option.get

+1 for the parser combinator-like approach.  A full-blown parser generator might be a bit too much for this task, so this is IMO the perfect solution for this problem.

I think we could define a new operator for composing multiple computations on 'a option value.
let ( |-> ) opt f =
  match opt with
  | Some _ -> opt
  | None -> f ()

...
  Option.map (fun i -> Num i) (int_of_string_opt s)
  |-> (fun () -> Option.map (fun b -> Bool b) (bool_of_string_opt s))
  |-> fun () -> Some (Var s)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
